# how to break down a str into a list

Tags: python

This is what I've done so far:

```
def file_to_dict(f):

""" (file open for reading) -> dict of {float: int}

f contains exchange rate changes as floating point numbers separated
by whitespace. Return a dict with exchange rate changes as keys and the
number of occurrences of the exchange rate changes as values.
"""

file = open(f, 'r')
data = list(file.read().strip().split('\n'))
```

The data is:

```
0.0045  0.0160 -0.0028 -0.0157 -0.0443 -0.0232 -0.0065 -0.0080  0.0052
-0.0052 -0.0283 -0.0087 -0.0020 -0.0080 -0.0065 -0.0290  0.0180  0.0030
-0.0170  0.0000 -0.0185 -0.0055  0.0148 -0.0053  0.0265 -0.0290  0.0010
-0.0015  0.0137 -0.0137 -0.0023  0.0008  0.0055 -0.0025 -0.0125  0.0040
```

How do I make each number an item in a list?
eg: `[0.0045, 0.0160, etc...] or ['0.0045', '0.0160', etc...]`

Comment: see my answer for additional help on the dictionary

Comment: This question's title can be improved for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
>>> with open('fileName', 'r') as f:
        newList = []
        for line in f:
            newList.extend(map(float, line.split()))


>>> newList
[0.0045, 0.016, -0.0028, -0.0157, -0.0443, -0.0232, -0.0065, -0.008, 0.0052, -0.0052, -0.0283, -0.0087, -0.002, -0.008, -0.0065, -0.029, 0.018, 0.003, -0.017, 0.0, -0.0185, -0.0055, 0.0148, -0.0053, 0.0265, -0.029, 0.001, -0.0015, 0.0137, -0.0137, -0.0023, 0.0008, 0.0055, -0.0025, -0.0125, 0.004]
```

Since, you can't use `map()`, do something like

```
>>> with open('fileName', 'r') as f:
        newList = []
        for line in f:
            for elem in line.strip().split():
                newList.append(float(elem))
```

Comment: I can't use the map function (we haven't learned it yet and therefore are supposed to use other methods). What I intuitively want to do is go data = list(file.read().strip().split('\n', ' ')) or data = list(file.read().strip().split('\n' and ' ')), but it seems that is not the nature of the split function

Comment: thanks, your method worked. I also found that doing data = list(file.read().strip().split() worked as well, giving each number as a list

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use map and probably no generators either, just use 2 for loops

Also it sounds like you are allowed to use strings to store your floats which will help your precision since float comparison is messy.

```
stringlist = []
with open('fileName', 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    for item in line.split():
        stringlist.append(item)        # this stores strings
```

**Spoiler** if you want to count the occurrences of these floats and store them in a dict as it seems is your assignment, you can do this:

```
myDict = {}
for value in stringlist:
    if value in myDict.keys():  # this would pose float comparison issues if you used float keys
        myDict[value] += 1
    else:
        myDict[value] = 1

print myDict
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension:

```
list_ = [
    float(number) for line in open("filename", "r") 
    for number in line.strip().split()
]
```